# Have RealmObject located in an Android Library

Tags: android, realm

I have an Android Studio project which contains the an app and a few Java and Android Libraries. app,db,logic, etc... The project is currently using realm 0.87.5. which was easily added to the db library with

```
compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.87.5'
```

All the RealmObject classes are stored inside the db Android Library. I would like to upgrade to realm 1.2, but the issue is being that realm now uses the gradle plugin I cannot use

```
apply: "realm-android"
```

on the db Library. Android Studio spits out errors. What would be the best way to achieve this without rearranging the entire code base?

Comment: Calling `apply plugin: "realm-android"` on the library should work without a problem, if there are issues then a Clean -> Rebuild should fix it. However, the breaking changes should be taken into consideration, such as the removal of the `refresh()` method, that `clear()` / `remove()` is now `delete()` and that commits don't immediately refresh existing RealmResults.

Comment: What kind of errors did you get ? which gradle file did you add the realm plugin ? Have you followed the installation guide ? [realm installation on Android Studio](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#installation)